# Make unique strings in a data frame

Tags: r, unique

I'd like to make a column of (possibly) non-unique strings into a column of unique strings.

For instance, consider:

```
df <- data.frame(
     'Initials' = c("AA","AB","AB")
     , 'Data' = c(1,2,3)
 )
df
  Initials Data
1       AA    1
2       AB    2
3       AB    3
```

I would like to obtain this:

```
  Initials Data    
1       AA        1
2       AB (1)    2
3       AB (2)    3
```

Note: I know I could use the rownames to uniquely identify the row, but I'd like to retain the string stored in the Initials column, with a number appended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
transform(df, Initials = ave(as.character(Initials), Initials, 
       FUN = function(x) if (length(x) > 1) paste0(x, " (", seq(x), ")") else x))

#   Initials Data
# 1       AA    1
# 2   AB (1)    2
# 3   AB (2)    3
```

Comment: I was going to suggest using `make.unique` on the `Initials` column, but this is more flexible-- not to mention meeting the OP's exact formatting request.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I played around with make.unique before asking the question, but couldn't make it to work (except on colnames). I like that the syntax here is easy to "read".

Comment: I would never have thought of looking up `ave`, which I have not used before. Hard to guess that 'Group Averages Over Level Combinations of Factors' can be useful here. And +1 for the super fast answer.

Comment: OK, I thought this was clear to me, but now I need to ask: exactly how does `seq(x)` work here?  I can't quite figure out how it acts on what I thought was a vector (`x`) of character elements. Consider: ` nfoo<-c('AA','AB','AB','AC','AA')` , then `ave((nfoo), nfoo, FUN = function(x) print(x) )` returns `[1] "AA" "AA"
[1] "AB" "AB"
[1] "AC"
[1] "AA" "AB" "AB" "AC" "AA"`   .  Where does that last line of values come from and given that it has length 5, why doesn't the `paste..seq(x)...`  do anything to the inputs?   Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh, never mind -- The first 3 outputs come from `print`; the last one is the output of `ave` .  Sorry.

Comment: No need to say sorry Carl, because your question and self-answer helped me understand more too.

Answer (score 2):

```
w <- ave(df$Data, df$Initials, FUN = seq_along )
> df$Initials <- paste(df$Initials, "(", w, ")", sep = "")
# > df
#   Initials Data
# 1    AA(1)    1
# 2    AB(1)    2
# 3    AB(2)    3
```

Comment: Almost, I would say, and probably good enough for the purpose. Strictly, a second pass would be needed to avoid the AA(1). Note: use paste0 for a shorthand instead of sep="".

Comment: +1: thanks user1317221_G! I selected for Sven's answer because 1) I find the syntax easier to read and 2) I'm trying to avoid the dollar syntax df$Data, which is giving me problems for a variety of reasons (the name Data is an input from a shiny reactive function, the dataframe sometimes has a single column, etc.). Again, I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

## TLDR

Can use `make_unique` from the  [makeunique](https://github.com/selkamand/makeunique) package (Disclaimer: I'm the author)

```r
# install.packages('makeunique')
library(makeunique)

df <- data.frame(
  Initials = c("AA","AB","AB"),
  Data = c(1,2,3)
)

df[['Initials']] <- make_unique(df[['Initials']])
df
#>   Initials Data
#> 1       AA    1
#> 2   AB (1)    2
#> 3   AB (2)    3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

## Full Answer

Disclaimer: I'm the author the [makeunique](https://github.com/selkamand/makeunique) package

The problem with @Sven Hohenstein's answer is that it can still produce duplicates. For example if your input dataset happens to include a string 'AB (2)'. See example of issue below

```r
df <- data.frame(
  Initials = c("AA","AB","AB", "AB (2)"),
  Data = c(1,2,3,4)
)
transform(df, Initials = ave(as.character(Initials), Initials, 
                             FUN = function(x) if (length(x) > 1) paste0(x, " (", seq(x), ")") else x))
#>   Initials Data
#> 1       AA    1
#> 2   AB (1)    2
#> 3   AB (2)    3
#> 4   AB (2)    4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Really you'd either want something like `make_unique` from the [makeunique](https://github.com/selkamand/makeunique) package that warns you when this happens and lets you change suffix formatting to fix the issue

```r
# install.packages('makeunique')
library(makeunique)
df <- data.frame(
  Initials = c("AA","AB","AB", "AB (2)"),
  Data = c(1,2,3,4)
)

df[['Initials']] <- make_unique(df[['Initials']])
#> Error in make_unique(df[["Initials"]]): make_unique failed to make vector unique.
#> This is because appending '  <dup_number>' to duplicate values led tocreation of term(s) that were in the original dataset: 
#> [AB (2)]
#> 
#> Please try again with a different argument for either `wrap_in_brackets` or `sep`

# Change suffix format to fix problem
df[['Initials']] <- make_unique(df[['Initials']], sep = "-")
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Or, you could make.unique from base R that ensures uniqueness but doesn't let you control how your suffixes look.

If you don't want to use a package, feel free to just copy the source function for `make_unique` into your code and use it like your own function

```
make_unique <- function(x, sep = " ", wrap_in_brackets = TRUE, warn_about_type_conversion = TRUE){
  if(!(is.character(sep) & length(sep) == 1)) stop('`sep` must be a string, not a ', paste0(class(sep), collapse = " "))
  if(!(is.logical(wrap_in_brackets) & length(wrap_in_brackets) == 1)) stop('`wrap_in_brackets` must be a flag, not a ', paste0(class(wrap_in_brackets), collapse = " "))
  if(!(is.logical(warn_about_type_conversion) & length(warn_about_type_conversion) == 1)) stop('`warn_about_type_conversion` must be a flag, not a ', paste0(class(warn_about_type_conversion), collapse = " "))
  if(!any(is.numeric(x),is.character(x),is.factor(x))) stop('input to `make_unique` must be a character, numeric, or factor variable')

  if(is.factor(x)) {
    if(warn_about_type_conversion) warning('make_unique: Converting factor to character variable')
    x <- as.character(x)
  }
  else if(is.numeric(x)) {
    if(warn_about_type_conversion) warning('make_unique: Converting numeric variable to a character vector')
    x <- as.character(x)
  }

  deduplicated = stats::ave(x, x, FUN = function(a){
    if(length(a) > 1){
      suffixes <- seq_along(a)
      if(wrap_in_brackets) suffixes <- paste0('(', suffixes, ')')
      paste0(a, sep, suffixes)
    }
    else {a}
  })

  values_still_duplicated <- deduplicated[duplicated(deduplicated)]

  if(length(stats::na.omit(values_still_duplicated)) > 0){
    stop(
      "make_unique failed to make vector unique.\n",
      "This is because appending '  <dup_number>' to duplicate values led to",
      "creation of term(s) that were in the original dataset: \n[",
      paste0(values_still_duplicated, collapse = ', '),
      "]\n\nPlease try again with a different argument for either `wrap_in_brackets` or `sep`"
    )
  }

  return(deduplicated)
}
```